# how to call a Jquery function on viewmodel contet update update

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a JQueryFunction for URL shortening.
like  `$(".comment").shorten();` 
which I usually call when the page is loaded.

I have a `DIV` tag and the content of which are getting populated through the Data-bind
like

```
<div style="float: left; margin: 5px 0px 0px 30px; width: 92%" class="comment">  

<span data-bind="text: Element.Abstract"  style="text-align: justify;"  />
```

I need any idea for where to call the  `$(".comment").shorten();`  function so that after the content is bound the function can shorten the content.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. Create a custom binding.

You can create custom bindings that are executed by KnockoutJS. You have both an option to run code on init and on update. Responding to both with your jQuery function would do the trick. You can then set your HTML to something like: `data-bind="shortenUrl: Element.Abstract"`

See the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for an example.

1. Extend your observable with read and write properties and respond to write.

You can treat your observables as properties with both a read and a write function. The write function can first call your jQuery function and then initialize the value.

See the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) for an example.

My preference would be a custom binding. It's a nice solution that can be used in multiple places without duplicating code.